# Is there a C equivalent of C++'s std::cin?

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to convert this code from C++ into C:

```cpp
int num{0};
std::cin >> num;
```

I need an equivalent to `std::cin`. I've already tried:

```c
int num = 0;
fgets (num, 0, stdin);
```

What can I do?

Comment: [Scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: `scanf ("%d", &num);`. `fgets` uses `num` as the destination byte buffer to store the input number as a string, and that's not what you want.

Comment: regarding; `fgets (num, 0, stdin);`  the second parameter `0` is the length of the input buffer.  Since the value of that length is 0, nothing will actually be input.

Answer (score 3):

> *Is there a C equivalent of C++'s std::cin*

Not really. The C++ `std::cin` represents a specific instance of the `std::istream` class, for which the `>>` (formatted input) operator has a number of overloads (at least one of which is templated). Thus, that one operator can effectively handle a variety of different input types.

The closest thing that C has is the `stdin` file handle, which (generally speaking) represents the same input stream as `std::cin`. However, although you can use `stdin` in [formatted input operations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) (like `fscanf`), you can also use the more general `scanf` function (which uses the same input stream).

However, you will need to specify the format options *explicitly*, for each input type (use `%d` for an `int` type), like so:

```c
    int num = 0;
    scanf("%d", &num);
```

Or, for the more 'general' case:

```c
    int num = 0;
    fscanf(stdin, "%d", &num);
```

Comment: @FullyAutomaticGames Always happy to help - that's what Stack Overflow is for! Feel free to [explore how SO works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).‎

Answer (score 0):

using `scanf ("%d", &var);`
scanf will put the value of the input directly into var.
it will wait until the user press Enter or any other key.